# entering student marks in excel sheet in python

Tags: python, xlrd, xlsxwriter

```
row = 1
col = 1
worksheet.write(1, 0, var)
for question in questions:
    worksheet.write(row, col, entry[question].get())
    col += 1
```

there is a user interface that takes "var" code and an entry set that takes student roll number and marks for few question. By using the code only one record is getting placed in excel file.if i enter another number and marks the existing value is over ridden by the new number and questions.what to do? I want another record also to be placed having the previous data in the sheet!

Comment: Please correct your message's formatting

Comment: iam totally new! please try to understand

Comment: You should've indented your code with four spaces instead of using the `` syntax for inline code. See Stack Overflows editing guide here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow by the way.

Comment: Thanx for the kind information.please look at my code